# не работает правильно Makefile нет iso файла

Tags: makefile

Работаю по Ubuntu 16.04 Учусь по видео урокам есть Makefile в котором не знаю как создать iso файл он просто не создаётся привожу данные из терминала:

```
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/TEST/MyOS$ make mykernel.iso
mkdir iso
mkdir iso/boot
mkdir iso/boot/grub
cp mykernel.bin iso/boot/
echo 'set timeout=0' > iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo 'set default=0' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo '' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo 'menuentry "My Operating System" {' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo '  multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo '  boot' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo '}' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkrescue --output=mykernel.iso iso
rm -rf iso
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/TEST/MyOS$
```

но mykernel.iso не создаётся привожу исходник Makefile:

```
GPPPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386

objects = loader.o kernel.o

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin

mykernel.iso: mykernel.bin
    mkdir iso
    mkdir iso/boot
    mkdir iso/boot/grub
    cp $< iso/boot/
    echo 'set timeout=0' > iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'set default=0' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'menuentry "My Operating System" {' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  boot' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '}' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    grub-mkrescue --output=$@ iso
    rm -rf iso

run: mykernel.iso
    VirtualBox --startvm "My Operating System" &
```

В чём у меня ошибка, заранее спасибо за ответ учитель работает на Mint Linux

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто под видео написано что: you need to install the packages VirtualBox, grub-legacy, xorriso, правда вместо grub-legacy я установил grub.
Вот и всё, моя система Ubuntu 16.04, правда диск iso так и не грузится приходится использовать QEMU с bin файлом